# Algorithm for computing algebraic numbers? (Why are algebraic numbers computable?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $b$ is algebraic over the rationals.

In other words:
$p(b) = 0$ for some polynomial where all the coefficients are rational.

I am told $b$ is computable. But why?

1. Can I derive a polynomial from $p$ that I can evaluate to get $b$?
   **edit:** commentor clearly pointed out no. Rationals are closed under those operations.
2. Is there some other algorithm for computing $b$ given the polynomial? **edit:** accepted answer: a root finding algorithm.
3. If not what is the general argument that algebraic numbers are computable? **edit**: an argument that the root finding algorithm will converge.

Comment: By multiplying and adding rational numbers we will always get rational numbers. Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "computable number"

Comment: @PVanchinathan You're right, I should have known. So that answers the first part. No, you can't evaluate a rational polynomial to get $b$. I'll update.

Comment: You should define what you mean by a computable number.  You can't get $\sqrt 2$ by finitely multiplying and adding rationals.  The [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) is that you can approximate it to any given precision with a finite algorithm.  In that case Newton's method applied to a polynomial makes all the roots computable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured that it had to be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that iterative root-finding algorithms, like the [Aberth method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method), exist to numerically find the roots of polynomials whose coefficients are themselves computable.  Therefore if `p(x)` has rational coefficients, there exists a program that will produce `b`.  So `b` is computable.

Comment: Makes sense. If I have the polynomial, I can use a root finding algorithm to approximate the solution $b$. Thanks.